# Count number of Divisors for all the numbers till N

Tags: java, algorithm, math

> I need to count all the divisors for every number in the range `1 to n`. I have written down below an implementation for, given an integer `num`, it counts the number of divisors of `num`. Its complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`. So over all complexity comes out to be `O(n * sqrt(n))`. Can it be reduced? If YES, then can you give an algorithm for that?

**CODE** :

```
 public static int countDivisors(int num)
    {
        int limit = (int)Math.sqrt(num);
        int count = 2;
        for(int i = 2 ; i <= limit ; i++)
        {
            if(num % i == 0)
            {
                count++;
                if(num / i != i)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

**PS:**
This function will be called `n` times.

Comment: It appears this code is working, so may be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: *"Can it be reduced?"* **Yes.** Was that all you wanted to know?

Comment: @Andreas, I have edited the question. If it can be reduced, then can you provide an algorithm for that?

Comment: Did you try Google, e.g. using the title of your question? [`Count number of Divisors for all the numbers till N`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Count+number+of+Divisors+for+all+the+numbers+till+N) --- Top link for me is [Count Divisors of n in O(n^1/3) - GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-divisors-n-on13/)

Comment: @Andreas you should take the link in geeksforgeeks with a large grain of salt. Try to read it in detail and you will notice the complexity is in fact O(n^2) for a single test case.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev But this question is not about a single test case, so what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @Andreas it is a single test case - you have to count all the divisors of the numbers up to n **once**

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev But you have to call `countDivisors` n times.

Comment: @Andreas please read the whole post in geeskforgeeks. You call the count divisors function n times, but before doing so you need to do n*n precomputation. Thus if you only do a single iteration, this is useless.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I did look, and I see no `n * n` precomputation in the `SieveOfEratosthenes` method. I am of course ignoring the unnecessary `primesquare[i] = false;` statement, since that is the default value of booleans in a new array. And a simplistic view of the `prime[i] = false;` statement, is that it executes `sqrt(n) * n` times, but it's actually much less than that when you factor in the prime check and the `i += p` increment.

Comment: @Andreas this line `bool prime[n+1], primesquare[n*n+1];` is already of square complexity.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev If you are referring to the zero-ing out of memory for the new array, then that very likely happens in the background when memory is allocated from OS and during/after GC, and is not part of the operation in question, i.e. it doesn't affect performance of the code, and is hence not affecting Big-O. The JVM is not execuing a loop initializing the array elements to `false` during the `new` operator call.

Comment: I am talking about the allocation of the memory. You can't ignore that when computing the complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve upon the naive approach using kind of a generalized [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Instead of just marking the number as composite also store its first divisor that you found (I do this in the function computeDivs below).

```
class Main
{
    // using Sieve of Eratosthenes to factorize all numbers
    public static int[] computeDivs(int size) {
      int[] divs = new int[size + 1];
      for (int i = 0; i <  size + 1; ++i) {
        divs[i] = 1;
      }
      int o = (int)Math.sqrt((double)size);
      for (int i = 2; i <= size; i += 2) {
        divs[i] = 2;
      }

      for (int i = 3; i <= size; i += 2) {
        if (divs[i] != 1) {
          continue;
        }
        divs[i] = i;
        if (i <= o) {
          for (int j = i * i; j < size; j += 2 * i) {
            divs[j] = i;
          }
        }
      }
      return divs;
    }

    // Counting the divisors using the standard fomula
    public static int countDivisors(int x, int[] divs) {
      int result = 1;
      int currentDivisor = divs[x];
      int currentCount = 1;
      while (currentDivisor != 1) {
        x /= currentDivisor;
        int newDivisor = divs[x];
        if (newDivisor != currentDivisor) {
          result *= currentCount + 1;
          currentDivisor = newDivisor;
          currentCount = 1;
        } else {
          currentCount++;
        }
      }
      if (x != 1) {
        result *= currentCount + 1;
      }

      return result;
    }


    public static int countAllDivisors(int upTo) {
      int[] divs = computeDivs(upTo + 1);
      int result = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= upTo; ++i) {
        result += countDivisors(i, divs);
      }
      return result;

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
      System.out.println(countAllDivisors(15));
    }
}
```

You can also see the code executed on ideone [here](https://ideone.com/i1Wp47).

In short I use the sieve to compute the biggest prime factor for each number. Using this I can compute the factor decomposition of every number very efficiently (and I use this in countDivisors).

It is hard to compute the complexity of the sieve but a standard estimate is `O(n * log(n))`. Also I am pretty confident it is not possible to improve on that complexity.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ivaylo. This answer of yours helped me learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do much better than `O(n.sqrt(n))` by using simple iteration. The code is in C++, but you can easily get the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void CountDivisors(int n) {
    vector<int> cnts(n + 1, 1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i; j <= n; j += i) {
            cnts[j]++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        cout << cnts[i] << " \n"[i == n];
    }
}

int main() {
    CountDivisors(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Running time is `n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + n/4 + ... + n/n` which can be approximated by `O(nH(n))`, where `H(n)` is the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). I think the value is not bigger than `O(nlog(n))`.

Comment: Thanks abdullah. This algo is surely faster than mine. But I have marked other answer as correct because i think its faster. I suggest you also look into it

Answer (score 0):

Using iteration is OK for relatively small numbers. As soon as the number of divisors is getting bigger (over 100-200), the iteration is going to take a significant amount of time.

A better approach would be to count the number of divisors with help of [prime factorization](https://www.cuemath.com/numbers/prime-factorization/) of the number.

So, express the number with prime factorization like this:

```java
  public static List<Integer> primeFactorizationOfTheNumber(long number) {
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    var remainder = number;
    var prime = 2;

    while (remainder != 1) {
      if (remainder % prime == 0) {
        primes.add(prime);
        remainder = remainder / prime;
      } else {
        prime++;
      }
    }
    return primes;
  }
```

Next, given the prime factorization, express it in the exponent form, get exponents and add `1` to each of them. Next, multiply resulting numbers. The result will be the count of divisors of a number. More on this [here](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Edeturck/m170/wk2/numdivisors.html).

```java
  private long numberOfDivisorsForNumber(long number) {
    var exponentsOfPrimeFactorization = primeFactorizationOfTheNumber(number)
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()))
      .values();
    return exponentsOfPrimeFactorization.stream().map(n -> n + 1).reduce(1L, Math::multiplyExact);
  }
```

This algorithm works very fast. For me, it finds a number with 500 divisors within less than a second.